# Editor Tabs and Upload Media Button missing from wp_editor

Tags: wordpress

I have created some custom fileds and I would like to use wp_editor on them.

I have this successfully working with the following:

```
$content = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_tab_test', true );
$editor_id = '_tab_test';
$settings = array( 'media_buttons' => true, 'textarea_name' => '_tab_test2', 'textarea_rows' => 20, 'quicktags' => false, 'tinymce' => true  );
wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings );
```

The editor loads correctly but the Upload Media button is not displayed and there are no tabs to switch between Visual and Text.

Is this a limitation of using the editor on a custom field or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

To show editor Tabs and Upload Media Button missing from wp_editor and it working for me.

```
<?php 
      $settings = array('wpautop' => false, 'textarea_name' => 'booking_to_user');
      $content = $message;
      $wpText_editor_id = "message_bookings_users";
      wp_editor( $content, $wpText_editor_id, $settings );
?>
```